# How to get selected data from datagrid (sql) to messagebox?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I found only solutions with manual created datagrid with binding.

Idk how to do it when I am getting data from SQL.

Let's say that I would need:

```
FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME   TELEPHONE
 TestFi     TestLa     1111111
 Testfa     TestAl     2222222
```

When I mouse click on first record in datagrid I would like to print only telephone.

Problem is that I am not even getting any data while using:

```
MessageBox.Show(dg.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

In messagebox it shows:

> System.Data.DataRowView

Could anyone say me why is that happening?

Comment: Sorry for duplicate. Every time I am googling as much as I can. I did not find original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SelectedItem is a DataRowView. So, you have to choose the column to display :

```
var row = (DataRowView)dg.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(row["phone"]);
```